# Problem running multiple MySQL instances

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run multiple instance of mysql 5.1.49 on ubuntu 10.10 to setup a replication/backup database. I have added following line to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld2]
server-id  = 2
socket     = /tmp/mysql2.sock
port       = 3308
pid-file   = /var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.pid
datadir    = /var/lib/mysql2
log-error  = /var/log/mysqld2/mysql2.log
user       = mysql
```

also I have done:

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql2
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql2
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql2
```

but when I run:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_install_db --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2 [--user=mysql]
```

as root or mysql user I get:

```
110627 17:04:17 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql2/david.lower-test
110627 17:04:17 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql2/david.lower-test

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/var/lib/mysql2 for more information.
...
```

and when I run `mysqld_multi --verbose --no-log start 2` I get:

```
110627 17:07:21 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql2/david.lower-test
110627 17:07:21 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql2/david.lower-test
110627 17:07:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
110627 17:07:21 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
110627 17:07:21  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Only `mysql` dir is create inside `/var/lib/mysql2/`.

Any idea?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're replicating the MySQL database on the same machine? Why? (I ask not to be a jerk, but because there might be an alternative solution for your final goal)

Comment: I'm trying to setup a backup strategy and I'm going to use the slave for backing up the master as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407124/best-practice-for-backing-up-a-production-mysql-database/407201#407201), any idea is welcomed.

Comment: that post recommends setting up a second MySQL Slave server - not another MySQL instance. If you lose the machine (networking issue, crashes, drives fail) than you have a second machine with the data replicated. This only saves you if your primary MySQL instance fails but the machine doesn't.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi - You are right, I also copy bin-logs to Amazon S3, but I still need to be able to take hot-backups without interrupting master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer [here](http://mysqlmusings.blogspot.com/2009/12/using-mysqldmulti-on-karmic.html). The problem was with AppArmor.